# Typescript Project outside Visual studio

Tags: typescript

Have anyone worked outside visual studio with a typescript project? Is there anything to be aware of?

I am using the typescript project tempalte in visual studio which takes care of compilig on save and all that.

I am introducing a guy tomorrow to the project with the goal of us getting him a non VS environment. He is using Sublime. There seem to be a few plugins for typescript in sublime, not sure which is best to use. Also what kind of configuration is need for compiling?

Is it possible to find out exactly what command VS compiles the projects with and we can create a small build script that can be run outside visual studio?

Comment: you can use the tsc.exe to compile manually. I'd use the official Sublime plugin from the official website.

Comment: Go to the "Output" window in Visual Studio, and for "show output from" select "Build" to see what is happening with `tsc`. You could easily setup a grunt style task to "watch" for file changes and automatically rebuild for example upon file save.

Comment: **Opinion**: sublime is OK for Typescript, but not having smart code-completion (intellisense) and more immediate syntax suggestions and language hinting, really makes TypeScript less compelling outside of an environment like VS or WebStorm for example. The compiler will catch issues, but having done the Sublime and TypeScript experiment for a week or two, I went back to VS and WebStorm. :)

Comment: If you can live with Eclipse, the palantir plugin does a much better job than Sublime, with intellisense, realtime error warnings, etc. https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript. I've been using this with a simple custom build script written in bash: `tsc --out ./bin/js/app.js ./typescript/app.ts --sourcemap --sourceRoot ../../typescript/`
I've had had a mostly positive experience, other than Eclipse being kind of sluggish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend setting up a grunt environment (https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts). Here is a video on getting started http://youtu.be/Km0DpfX5ZxM (disclaimer one of the authors of grunt-ts)

Comment: Looks good. Will give that a try for starters